# IIS 7 URL Rewrite force redirect http --> https

Tags: iis-7, https, url-rewriting

I'm using an SSL wildcard certificate in IIS 7 and I'm trying to force the following redirect:

**The wildcard certificate is : *.domain.com**

```
http://client1.domain.com ----> https://client1.domain.com
```

I used the IIS 7 URL rewrite snap in to create the following rewrite rule in the XML configuration, which works properly if I'm using a regular non-wildcard certificate.  Anyone know if I'm missing anything a step?

```
<rewrite>   
  <rules>     
    <rule name="client1.domain.com" stopProcessing="true">      
      <match url=".*"/>       
      <conditions>         
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off"/>         
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^client1\.domain\.com$"/>         
      </conditions>       
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{URL}"/>       
    </rule>     
  </rules>   
</rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the rewrite wasn't getting invoked, so I re-installed the URL Rewrite IIS snap-in.